# Setting HTML text to a JS variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, text, tags

I want to take text from an html tag and save it in a js variable. What I am looking at is this:

JavaScript:

```
function Myfunction(){
  var x; //Fist num here
  var y; //second num here
  var z=x+y;
  alert(z);
}
```

HTML:

```
<p id="num1">2</p>
<p id="num2">3</p>
```

I am working on  a calculator and want to take the values from the "screen" and save them to a variable, to do math with. Each number is separated like this in the calc program:

```
<samp id="numb1">Any Number</samp><samp id="op">(+,-,*,/)</samp><samp id="numb2">Any Number</samp><samp id="answer">Answer prints here</samp>
```

Once the answer is saved to a variable, the numb1, op, and numb2 are cleared and answer is printed.

Comment: `samp` tag is used to achieve richer text effect. And if you **want to take the values from the "screen"** you need to take `input` tags..having said that you can either use `document.getElementById('numb1').innerHTML` or `document.getElementById('numb1').textContent` to retrieve the values which will be of `string` type, so before adding convert to number type using `parseInt`

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar Thanks so much You gave me the complete answer! It works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could access the node content and store the variable like that:

```
var vAnswer = document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML;
```

Comment: Now I get "[object HTMLelement] as an answer?

Comment: sorry maybe typo: Elment -> Element!??

Comment: and `.innerHTML`! ...and it should contain the content of @id="answer" tag (a string)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = document.getElementById('numb1').innerHTML;
var y = document.getElementById('numb2').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = parseInt(x,10) + parseInt(y,10);
```

```html
<samp id="numb1">2</samp>
<samp id="op">(+,-,*,/)</samp>
<samp id="numb2">3</samp>
<samp id="answer"></samp>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery, you can get the value as shown below,

```js
var x = $('#numb1').text();
var y = $('#numb2').text();
var z  =parseInt(x,10) +parseInt(y,10);
$('#answer').text('Total:'+z)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<samp id="numb1">2</samp>
<samp id="op">(+,-,*,/)</samp>
<samp id="numb2">3</samp>
<samp id="answer"></samp>
```

using javascript alone, use var x = document.getElementById('numb1').innerHTML;

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(){
  var x; //Fist num here
var y; //second num here
    x = $("#num1").text();
    y = $("#num2").text();
    alert(x);
    alert(y);
var z=parseInt(x,10)+parseInt(y,10);
alert(z);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want that to be a form? You'll probably want something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function calc() {
                var leftInput = document.getElementById("left"),
                    left = parseInt(leftInput.value, 10),
                    operatorSelect = document.getElementById("operator"),
                    operator = operatorSelect.options[operatorSelect.selectedIndex].value,
                    rightInput = document.getElementById("right"),
                    right = parseInt(rightInput.value, 10),
                    expression = left + operator + right,
                    resultSpan = document.getElementById("result");
                resultSpan.innerHTML = eval(expression);
                leftInput.value = '';
                rightInput.value = '';
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="left">
            <select id="operator">
                <option value="+">+</option>
                <option value="-">-</option>
                <option value="*">*</option>
                <option value="/">/</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" id="right">
            <input type="button" onclick="calc()" value="=">
            <span id="result"></span>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```